# XML parsing in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I do have the following xml response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UDSObjectList>
<UDSObject>
    <Handle>zLanguage:400001</Handle>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute DataType="2001">
            <AttrName>id</AttrName>
            <AttrValue>400001</AttrValue>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute DataType="2002">
            <AttrName>LngCode</AttrName>
            <AttrValue>deu</AttrValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</UDSObject>
<UDSObject>
    <Handle>zLanguage:400002</Handle>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute DataType="2001">
            <AttrName>id</AttrName>
            <AttrValue>400002</AttrValue>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute DataType="2002">
            <AttrName>LngCode</AttrName>
            <AttrValue>eng</AttrValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</UDSObject>
</UDSObjectList>
```

How can I get the `AttrValue` value based on the `AttrName` value?

For example, when the attribute name equal "id", I need to get its corresponding attribute value which is 400001 or 400002 in the previous response. Another example, when the attribute name equal "LngCode", I need to get its corresponding attribute value which is eng or deu in the previous response!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried?  Maybe you could get started by reading about [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Comment: Is it just the `AttrName`? If you query for `id` or `LngCode` the result is not unique. Do you want to retrieve all entries for the given `AttrName` or just a specific one?

Comment: Yes Markus, I want to retrieve all entries for the given AttrName @Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code;

```
    string myFilter = "LngCode";
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\temp.xml");
    var elements = xDoc.Descendants("AttrName")
        .Where(d => d.Value.Equals(myFilter))
        .Select(d => d.ElementsAfterSelf().FirstOrDefault());

    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
    }
```